# Maximum wireless output power

Tags: wireless-networking, power, ieee802.1x

What is the maximum wireless output power allowed by the FCC in the US without a license?
I am specifically wondering aboot IEEE802.15, but I'm assuming that it would be the same as IEEE802.11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look here](http://www.wlanantennas.com/faq.php#fcc).  According to what I found, 4 watts EIRP at the antenna.

Comment: No worries.  Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

So as not to encroach on the reserved areas of the adjacent frequencies, you need to stay within the limits of +20dBm (100mW) maximum output power.

There is also the consideration of which class of Bluetooth (I'm assuming that Bluetooth is what you are using) you are implementing.  The class limitations are listed here:

Class 1: 20 dBm Max. (100mW)

Class 2: 4 dBm (2.5 mW)

Class 3: 0 dBm (1mW)

---

I Hope This Helps...